# How to add email hyperlink in ireport

Tags: jasper-reports, pdf-generation, ireport, export-to-pdf

[image][image][image]Hi I'm using the ireport to generate the pdf, does anybody know how to add email hyperlink in ireport, so you click the email address, it will launch your mailbox.
What I did is:

```
   1. drag a text field
   2. right click and select "Hyperlink"
   3. Hyperlink target: Self
   4. Hyperlink type: Reference
   5. Hyperlink Reference expression: mailto:"business@xxx.com"
```

but it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.  You shouldn't have quotes before and after the email, but around the entire string.  Try this in the reference expression:

```
"mailto:business@example.com"
```

Tested on iReport 5.6 export to PDF.

Comment: Hi @stevenCrawford, I tried "mailto:business@xxx.com" but it still doesn't work at all, I attached all the screenshot of my ireport, could you please take a look to see if it's the same as yours? Thank you

Comment: You have it set up correctly; Our JRXML is identical.  Mine works in PDF/XHTML, but not using the built in viewer. Your issue could be related to config (either in your PDF viewer, or on your PC).  It also could be a Jasper issue (I've run into other hyperlink bugs in the past).  A way to check would be to export to XHTML and inspect the link with Chrome/Firefox debug tools.  If it's wrapped in a <a> tag, it's probably a config setting. Otherwise, it's probably a jasper issue.